# How would a Mars rover identify a microbialite fossil?

Tags: paleontology, fossils, astrobiology, planetology

I recently read of a company in Canada using [robotic technology](http://www.nanaimobulletin.com/news/255397371.html) to [study freshwater microbialites](http://www.pavilionlake.com/). Their claim is that greater understanding of terrestrial microbialites could help in the search for extraterrestrial microbialite fossils (if they exist) on Mars.

If a rover encountered a microbialite fossil on Mars, how would it identify the rock as being a fossil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm basing this answer off an article: *Kevin Lepot, Karim Benzerara, Gordon E. Brown Jr., Pascal Philippot (2008). 'Microbially influenced formation of 2.7 billion-year-old stromatolites'. Nature Geoscience Vol.1 No.2, pp.118–121*. DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ngeo107

Instruments that are desirable (and are actually used) to study stromatolites/freshwater microbialites:

- Raman microspectroscope
- Confocal laser scanning microscope
- Scanning transmission X-ray microscope
- Transmission electron microscope (TEM), including high-resolution TEM
- Near-edge X-ray absorption fine structure spectroscope
- The usual sets of fine analytical chemistry and microcutting tools

As you might suspect, this may require rather massive, power-hungry and bulky rovers. There is a solution and it's called **sample return**. Although the tools and instruments are constantly evolving and undergoing miniaturization, a skilled and attentive lab researcher will find out more back here on Earth than a rover on Mars.

Another consideration in favor of sample return is the verifiability of possibly sensational results - the sample will be curated and subdivided between universities and labs worldwide, applying diverse techniques and not relying on a single set of ultra-costly but possibly systematically biased hardware.

Comment: Thanks for including the reference, unfortunately that uri is unavailable (both here and on Wikipedia.)

Comment: I understand how SEM and TEM could provide morphological evidence for a biological origin, but what features would we look for? I don't see how Raman or X-ray spectroscopy would be applicable - are you suggesting it might show evidence of organic material?

Comment: I take your answer as: "sample return." Which is reasonable, if also a bit disappointing. I'm marking this as answered.

Comment: @MarkRovetta - the article looks for nanoscale structures, hence the choice of instruments. It *is* possible to pack a robotic lab on a Mars lander (6-7 metric tonnes).